# Find the potential function of a conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My lecture notes are confusing me here:

They state that if $\phi(x,y,z)$ is a scalar function, then its gradient is a vector field $$F(x,y,z) := \nabla \phi$$

Why is the gradient a vector field?

Then it goes on to say

if $F(x,y,z)$ represents a gradient of some scalar function $\phi(x,y,z)$
then $F(x,y,z)$ is a conservative or potential vector field 
and $\phi(x,y,z)$ is called the potential function of $F(x,y,z)$.

We just learned that if the curl is zero then it is a conservative vector field ?

I'm going to guess at what this means :

If you have a scalar function $\phi(x,y,z)$ this means any old function of $x$, $y$, and $z$ then you calculate its gradient as a for a vector field $$\frac{d}{dx}i + \frac{d}{dy}j + \frac{d}{dz}k$$

Then we know that the function $F(x,y,z)$ is a conservative vector field i.e., one with a curl of zero and the scalar function is called the potential function of $F(x,y,z)$

I also don't understand why this is the case? Does it have something to do with the initial vector function being a scalar and not a vector? I can do the calculations but I am just guessing at what is actually happening, would someone please be able to help with a clear explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: $circlewithalinethroughit$?

Comment: I assume OP means $\phi$. I've changed the post accordingly, but please correct me if any of my guesses are wrong. Also, OP, the symbol $\nabla$ is spelled *nabla*, "nambla" is something else entirely...

Comment: "Circle with "that" line in it" ...the empty set $\;\emptyset\;$ ? The greek letter phi $\;\Phi\;,\;\;or\;\;\phi\;$ ? Do you *really* don't know this and you're studying mathematics? And even if we know (of course, the empty set cannot be), **what** is the definition of that circlewiththatlineinit, which most probably is a function?

Comment: @Timbuc Often students haven't encountered many Greek letters by the time they start multivariable calculus, except perhaps $\alpha$, $\theta$, and $\pi$, and maybe a few more if they've taken a little physics.

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know this about the Greek letters. I didn't know that but now I do ! Next time I don't know what a symbol is I can google Greek Alphabet ! Travis you are correct in your guesses. Thanks.

Comment: @Travis, that sounds simply umbelievable, but I'll take your word for it. I think it is a huge hole in basic education.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, the reason the gradient of a scalar-valued function is a vector field is:
$$ \nabla \phi = \langle \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \rangle $$
which is the formula for a vector field. For each point $p$ in some region of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we assign $\nabla \phi (p)$. This makes $\nabla \phi$ a vector field.

Now, if $\vec{F} = \nabla \phi$ then $\nabla \times \vec{F} = \nabla \times \nabla \phi = 0$. However, the converse is not necessarily true. It is possible to have $\nabla \times \vec{F} =0$ throughout some domain $U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and yet there does not exist $\phi$ on all of $U$ such that $\nabla \phi = \vec{F}$. If you want the curl vanishing to imply the existence of the **potential function** $\phi$ then you also need to have a **topological condition** on $U$. In particular, if $U$ is simply connected then we can apply Stokes' Theorem to arbitrary surfaces in $U$ and for each surface $S$:
$$ \int_{\partial S} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot d\vec{S} = 0.$$
Hence integrals of $\vec{F}$ around loops in $U$ vanish hence $\vec{F}$ is path-independent and then we can prove $\displaystyle \phi(\vec{r}) = \int_{p}^{\vec{r}} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ is a valid formula for the construction of a potential in $U$.

In any event, if you are currently taking multivariate calculus and you were just introduced to conservative vector fields then relax. In a week or two these things should all gel together. There are a few moving pieces, but, once you see how they all fit it's really pretty. We have the following equivalence:
Suppose $U$ is an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the following are equivalent

1. $\vec{F}$ is conservative; $\vec{F}=\nabla \phi$ on all of $U$
2. $\vec{F}$ is path-independent on $U$
3. $\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} =0$ for all closed curves $C$ in $U$
4. (add condition $U$ be simply connected)  $\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$ on $U$.